# Python Sqlite UPDATE with 3 parameters

Tags: python

Good evening. I have a fairly basic python application that loads an sqlite database into a gui and provides the user crud functionality.

My add and delete functions work properly but I am struggling to query the update without issue.

I need to craft this update statement out of 3 variables
**self.tempColumn** : the name of the desired column to update
**cheese_id** : the id of the record to update
**value** : the value to update the field with

I have printed out all 3 of these values and they return what I am expecting, however I cannot run the update query without crashing.

```
    def run_query(self, query, parameters=()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
        return result



    def delete_record(self, cheese_id):

    query = 'DELETE FROM ' + self.working_table + " where CheeseId=" + cheese_id
    self.run_query(query, )
```

delete_record works

```
    def add_record(self, cheese_id, cheese_name_en, manufacturer_name_en,
               manufacturer_prov_code, manufacturing_type_en, website_en,
               fat_content_percent, moisture_percent, particularities_en, flavour_en,
               characteristics_en, ripening_en, organic, category_type_en,
               milk_type_en, milk_treatment_type_en, rind_type_en,
               last_update_date):
    print(cheese_id)

    sql_insert_query = '''INSERT INTO cheeseData(CheeseId, CheeseNameEn, ManufacturerNameEn,
                     ManufacturerProvCode, ManufacturingTypeEn, WebSiteEn,
                     FatContentPercent, MoisturePercent, ParticularitiesEn, FlavourEn,
                     CharacteristicsEn, RipeningEn, Organic, CategoryTypeEn,
                     MilkTypeEn, MilkTreatmentTypeEn, RindTypeEn,
                     LastUpdateDate)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''

    parameters = (cheese_id, cheese_name_en, manufacturer_name_en,
                  manufacturer_prov_code, manufacturing_type_en, website_en,
                  fat_content_percent, moisture_percent, particularities_en, flavour_en,
                  characteristics_en, ripening_en, organic, category_type_en,
                  milk_type_en, milk_treatment_type_en, rind_type_en,
                  last_update_date)
    print("about to run query add in datacess")

    self.run_query(sql_insert_query, parameters)
    print("query succcessful")
```

add record works

```
    def edit_record(self, cheese_id, value):
    if column == 0:
        self.tempColumn = "CheeseId"
    elif column == 1:
        self.tempColumn = "CheeseNameEn"
    elif column == 2:
        self.tempColumn = "ManufacturerNameEn"
    elif column == 3:
        self.tempColumn = "ManufacturerProvCode"
    elif column == 4:
        self.tempColumn = "ManufacturingTypeEn"
    elif column == 5:
        self.tempColumn = "WebSiteEn"
    elif column == 6:
        self.tempColumn = "FatContentPercent"
    elif column == 7:
        self.tempColumn = "MoisturePercent"
    elif column == 8:
        self.tempColumn = "ParticularitiesEn"
    elif column == 9:
        self.tempColumn = "FlavourEn"
    elif column == 10:
        self.tempColumn = "CharacteristicsEn"
    elif column == 11:
        self.tempColumn = "RipeningEn"
    elif column == 12:
        self.tempColumn = "Organic"
    elif column == 13:
        self.tempColumn = "CategoryTypeEn"
    elif column == 14:
        self.tempColumn = "MilkTypeEn"
    elif column == 15:
        self.tempColumn = "MilkTreatmentTypeEn"
    elif column == 16:
        self.tempColumn = "RindTypeEn"
    elif column == 17:
        self.tempColumn = "LastUpdateDateEn"
    print(self.tempColumn)
    conn = sqlite3.connect('canadianCheeseDirectory')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE cheeseData SET " + self.tempColumn + ' = ' + value + " WHERE CheeseId=" + cheese_id)
```

this does not work :(

I have tried many forms of this to no avail  including

```
self.run_query(
        """UPDATE cheeseData SET {}=? WHERE CheeseId = ?""".format(self.tempColumn),
        (value, cheese_id), )




self.run_query('UPDATE cheeseData set %s=%s WHERE CheeseId = $s'(self.tempColumn, value, cheese_id))
self.run_query('UPDATE cheeseData set %s=? WHERE CheeseId = ?VALUES(?,?)'.format(self.tempColumn)value, cheeseid)
```

I realize it is bad practice to concatenate strings for queries but this is a simple application on a local sqlite db file and I am simply trying to provide a gui crud.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For debugging, get the `UPDATE` statement into one string and print it on console to see whether it looks fine. Also try to run the same command in SqlLite command line and see if it gives any error.

Comment: Thank you @anuragal that was incredible advice. I managed to print out the statement until it seemed fitting and not it works with 

`query = """UPDATE cheeseData SET {}={} WHERE CheeseId={}""".format(self.tempColumn, value, cheese_id)`

Comment: Good to know :-)